# INSERT INTO ... FROM SELECT ... RETURNING id mappings

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-returning

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

I want to duplicate some of the db records. Since I'm using an auto-increment pk id for the table, I want to get back the id mappings from the generated ids of duplicated records to the original ones. For example, say I have a table `posts` with 2 records in it:

```
 [{'id': 1, 'title': 'first'}
, {'id': 2. 'title': 'second'}]
```

With SQL:

```
INSERT INTO posts (title) SELECT title FROM posts RETURNING id, ??
```

I expect to see mappings like:

```
 [{'id': 3, 'from_id': 1}
, {'id': 4, 'from_id': 2}]
```

Any idea on how to fill in the question marks above to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I thought you might be able to do it by aliasing: `FROM posts oldposts`, then referencing the old and new aliases in the `RETURNING` clause. It doesn't look like it though. Tricky.

Comment: @CraigRinger yeah, I tried that too. Wondering why it doesn't work that way.

Comment: it's a near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115941 which has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This would be simpler for `UPDATE`, where additional rows joined into the update are visible to the `RETURNING` clause:

- [Return pre-UPDATE column values using SQL only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923237/return-pre-update-column-values-using-sql-only-postgresql-version/7927957#7927957)

The same is currently ***not*** possible for `INSERT`. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> The expression can use any column names of the table named by *table_name*

*table_name* being the target of the `INSERT` command.

You can use [(data-modifying) CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to get this to work.
Assuming `title` to be *unique per query*, else you need to do more:

```sql
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT id, title
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  id IN (1,2)   -- select rows to copy
   )
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO posts (title)
   SELECT title FROM sel
   RETURNING id, title
 )
SELECT ins.id, sel.id AS from_id
FROM   ins
JOIN   sel USING (title);
```

If `title` is not unique per query (but at least `id` is unique per table):

```sql
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT id, title, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  id IN (1,2)   -- select rows to copy
   ORDER  BY id
   )
, ins AS (
   INSERT INTO posts (title)
   SELECT title FROM sel ORDER  BY id  -- ORDER redundant to be sure
   RETURNING id
 )
SELECT i.id, s.id AS from_id
FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM ins) i
JOIN   sel s USING (rn);
```

This second query relies on the undocumented implementation detail that rows are inserted in the order provided. It works in all current versions of Postgres and is probably not going to break.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fdb2e25362fc8bcd6e7f188793e38e75)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2deb9/1)</sub>

Comment: great answer. the second last row in the second query should have the column alias outside of the partition clause `FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM ins) i`

Comment: Re "*query relies on the undocumented implementation detail that rows are inserted in the order provided*", @AdrianKlaver [pointed me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76518722/postgresql-copy-the-table-rows-and-get-the-old-new-matching-information#comment134916842_76518722) to https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1678721.1681566044%40sss.pgh.pa.us where Tom Lane wrote "*We […] rejected the idea that INSERT must preserve the order of
the incoming tuples.*"

Answer (score 7):

if `id` column of `posts` is `serial` type, it's generated like `nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)`,
you can manually call this function for every new row

```
with
sel as (
  SELECT id, title, nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass) new_id
  FROM   posts
  WHERE  id IN (1,2)
),
ins as (
  INSERT INTO posts (id, title)
  SELECT new_id, title
  FROM sel
)
SELECT id, new_id
FROM sel
```

it'l works with any data, include non-unique `title`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter What is your opinion on this method?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution IMHO would be to simply add a column to your table where you could put id of the row that was cloned.

Comment: Yep, this may be the simplest and may also fit in other SQL dbs. But it adds additional complexity to db schema.