# How to return a mapping of old_ids and duplicated row's new_ids from a PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a postgreSQL function that duplicates all rows of a table by for the specified condition and return the mapping of existing row ids and duplicated row ids.

Here is the example data that I want to work with.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 6),
  foo_content text NOT NULL,
  condition_col integer NOT  NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE VALUES
(  1 , 'Sing, O goddess', 99),
(  2 , 'the anger of Achilles', 99),
(  3 , 'son of Peleus', 99),
(  4 , 'that brought countless ills', 2),
(  5 , 'upon the Achaeans', 3);

SELECT * FROM foo;
```

This is my attempt of writing the SQL function that is able to duplicate the entries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duplicate_entries(condition INT, new_condition INT)
RETURNS TABLE (
        old_id INT,
        new_id INT) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY (
        WITH select_cte AS (
            SELECT id
            FROM foo f
            WHERE f.condition_col = condition
        ), insertion_cte AS (
            INSERT INTO foo (foo_content, condition_col)
            SELECT f.foo_content, new_condition
            FROM select_cte s
            JOIN foo f ON s.id = f.id
            RETURNING id
        )
        --- how to I return a mapping of ids from here?
    );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- To call the function and get the result
SELECT * FROM duplicate_entries(99, 100);

-- To see the updated 'foo' table
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Here although I have achieved the desired function, I am unable to return the mapping of old_ids and new_ids from this function.

The returning table should look like this. I have tried to use a UNION ALL query but does not seem to do the trick. I think maybe a temp table would help in this case but I don't want to use a temp table as that may be a bad practice.

This is is what my desired output should look like:

| old_ids | new_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |

Comment: See [copy the table rows and get the old-new matching information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76518722/1048572) and related questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but probably shouldn't, [rely on the order of inserted rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29263402/1048572) to match between the selection and the `RETURNING` clause. A better approach is to generate the new ids ahead of the insert, using [the sequence that is underlying the identity column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187708/188406):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duplicate_entries(condition INT, new_condition INT)
RETURNS TABLE (old_id INT, new_id INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
  WITH mapping AS (
    SELECT id AS old_id, nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('foo', 'id')) AS new_id
    FROM foo f
    WHERE f.condition_col = condition
  ), __insertion AS (
    INSERT INTO foo (id, foo_content, condition_col)
    OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE
    SELECT m.new_id, f.foo_content, new_condition
    FROM mapping m
    JOIN foo f ON m.old_id = f.id
  )
  TABLE mapping;
END;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vB7MCcbp))</sup>

This does however require `USAGE` permission on the underlying sequence, which may not be granted by default even if a role can normally use the identity column. You may need to use `SECURITY DEFINER` on the function.

Comment: Playing with a non-default permission is not ideal, but it still works for me. I am wondering if there is any performance advantage in creating new IDs using `nextval()` instead of using literals to inject old IDs as suggested by @Zegarek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77158175/13376542)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that using a single SQL query is more performant than a pl/pgsql loop that fires off a lot of single-row inserts, but you still should benchmark it yourself with different numbers of rows to duplicate.

Comment: I can agree. Doing all three things at once and in bulk is simpler and faster. I initially wanted to only leave a comment confirming that you simply can't do it via `returning` clause but ended up expanding the *unless you inject literals* remark into an example.

Comment: @Zegarek Btw I wouldn't call them "literals" but rather "constants".

Comment: I would. The doc is in fact dominated by the use of *constant* rather than *literal* but it does seem to allow their interchangeability: [*"A token can be a key word, an identifier, a quoted identifier, a* ***literal (or constant),*** *or a special character symbol."*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) You could argue that's referring the same thing from different perspectives, kind of like in the *parameter vs argument* argument. You could also add that to PL/pgSQL it's neither *literal* nor *constant*, rather a *variable* assigned from an identifier. But why

Comment: @Zegarek Oh I didn't mean that kind of constant. It's not a literal. It's an identifier referring to a variable whose value is constant during the query execution, hence "constant".

Answer (score 0):

You can only use literals or stuff from the inserted data in your [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.5) clause. You can [iterate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) over the records you're duplicating and inject them as literals: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mnbQpZsP)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION duplicate_entries(condition INT, new_condition INT)
RETURNS TABLE (
        old_id INT,
        new_id INT) AS
$f$
DECLARE v_old_id int;
        v_foo_content text;
BEGIN
    FOR v_old_id, v_foo_content IN 
            SELECT id, foo_content
            FROM foo f
            WHERE f.condition_col = condition
    LOOP
    RETURN QUERY (
        WITH insertion_cte AS (
            INSERT INTO foo AS n (foo_content, condition_col) 
            VALUES (v_foo_content, new_condition)
            RETURNING v_old_id as old_id, n.id as new_id
        )
        select * from insertion_cte i
    );
    END LOOP;
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- To call the function and get the result
SELECT * FROM duplicate_entries(99, 100);

-- To see the updated 'foo' table
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

| old_id | new_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |

| id | foo_content | condition_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sing, O goddess | 99 |
| 2 | the anger of Achilles | 99 |
| 3 | son of Peleus | 99 |
| 4 | that brought countless ills | 2 |
| 5 | upon the Achaeans | 3 |
| 6 | Sing, O goddess | 99 |
| 7 | the anger of Achilles | 99 |
| 8 | son of Peleus | 99 |